# How to make a page with header and left-sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to make a webpage like this:

```
|----------------------------|
|            header          |
|----------------------------|
|  L  |                      |
|  e  |                      |
|  f  |                      |
|  t  |                      |
|     |                      |
|  S  |   Content Area       |
|  i  |                      |
|  d  |                      |
|  e  |                      |
|  b  |                      |
|  a  |                      |
|  r  |                      |
|----------------------------|
```

The header has a fixed height but it's width should be dynamic. The left-sidebar should have a fixed width but a dynamic height. For the content area, both height and width are dynamic. When user scale their browser, the scrolling bar should not appear(not set overflow:hidden; to hide it.).

I tried to write code like this:

```
<div class="top">
    TOP
</div>
<div class="left">
    LEFT
</div>
<div class="main">
    MAIN
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
.top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 92px;
}
.left {
    width: 178px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}
.main {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

But it failed.

**EDIT: Content Area and Left-SideBar must fill the whole browser window.....
I don't need**

```
|----------------------------|
|            header          |
|----------------------------|
|  L  |                      |
|  e  |                      |
|  f  |                      |
|  t  |                      |
|     |                      |
|  S  |   Content Area       |
|  i  |                      |
|  d  |----------------------|
|  e  |
|  b  |
|  a  |
|  r  |
|-----|
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/cxQGc/)

```
.top {
    position:absolute;
    left:0; right:0;
    height: 92px;
}
.left {
    position:absolute;
    left:0; top:92px; bottom: 0;
    width: 178px;
}
.main {
    position: absolute;
    left:178px; top:92px; right:0; bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: @Lee. use Position is difficult to cross browser, try using float.

Comment: @sandeeppattanaik In which browser, specifically, is my example failing?  It's true that, if you go way back to some really old browsers, then `bottom`, and `right` won't work the same.  If you need to support such ancient technology, then you will have to use some additional tricks (and `float` is just one of the tools in that particular toolbox).  However, even in old browsers, for a full-window elastic layout, `position:absolute` is still (usually) the easiest way.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the simple code for you. Try this & know the quality `CSS` coding.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="top">TOP</div>
<div class="left">LEFT</div>
<div class="right">MAIN</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear{
clear:both;
} 
.main{
width:500px;
}
.top {
background: blue;
width:500px;
height: 92px;
}
.left {
float:left;
width: 150px;
background: red;
}
.right{
float:right;
width:350px;
background: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***[LIve demo](http://tinkerbin.com/4iUXfEdJ)***

Hi now you just do easily as like this

**Css**

```
.top {
    height: 92px;
}
.left {
    width: 178px;
    float:left;
}
.main {
  margin-left:178px;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="top">
    TOP
</div>
<div class="left">
    LEFT
</div>
<div class="main">
N content here MAIN content here MAIN content here </div>
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/tph5goZ8)***

### ------------

***[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/5AUMA/)***

Comment: Nice, I also like margin-left, better than make both .left and .main float left.

Comment: It seems that the content area and left side-bar are not as height as my browser window... I need both these two areas fill the whole browser window...

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove `"float: left;"` from your `.main` definition.

Also, when debugging positioning this really helps:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Also it might be worth dropping `height: 100%` from .left and .main to prevent vertical scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/nRQeA/

```
.top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 92px;

}
.left {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
}
.main {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%

 }
```

Comment: I need to make left-sidebar and content area fill the whole browser window... like the finger I draw :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *display : table* and *display : table-cell* to create a page that holds a table-level element with 2 table-cells (sidebar & content area)

[image: Sample Image]

```
<div id="outer-container">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>

#outer-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#content {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 85%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

A tutorial with a demo here : http://usefulangle.com/post/61/html-page-with-left-sidebar-main-content-with-css

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie to css, but I've been familiar with html.  I took over a website created by someone else who extensively used tables for web page placements.  I'm redoing one page of the website, leaving out the tables.  I'm making a comment on Lee's solution above in 2012.  I made his solution work by adding "top:0;" as a property to the top css class.  I figured I could do this since I note that left is also a property for the left css class in Lee's solution.  I imagine Lee's solution, as is, was not working for me since there must be a conflict in the existing css file that was created by someone else.