# How to set 100% height on a sidebar div?

Tags: html, css, position, height, sidebar

I'm trying to figure out a way to display a sidebar inside a div so it will take 100% of the available height.

The code is available here.
HTML - http://pastebin.com/4nBe2KQS
CSS - http://pastebin.com/r63bREbb

I have already tried a lot of answers I found like removing the block elements, setting the body height, stating de div position as relative, inserting and empty div after the sidebar and so on, but none of them seem to work properly, the only way I got it working is through an absolute position but in this way the entire positioning of the site breaks.

The sidebar is recognized as div id='menuIzquierda' and the whole page is made up from different php files, I don't know if this may affect the performing of the css rendering.

I would really appreciate if someone could help since I am stuck at this point.

Edit: There are two other css files but they shouldn't affect the performance since one only styles the buttons and the other one depends on the url, and the positioning isn't working on any url.
Anyhow, i'll post them in the comments

Comment: did you try `height: 100%;`

Comment: Yes, I've also tried min-height 100% which should also work but it doesn't

Comment: CSS files - http://pastebin.com/mhBRAYqr, http://pastebin.com/LRwD4a1L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So try this and see if it works. I tried it on my computer and it works great.

## menuIzquierda {

```
margin-top: 25px;
float: left;
background-color: #333333;
position: fixed;
width: 20%;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

}

So the position: fixed will lock it in place and then the top: 0, bottom: 0 and left 0; will make it go full height.

Comment: I've tried this, it appears to work but it covers the top menu of the site letting unavailable the home button since it positions the sidebar at the beginning of the site

Comment: huh that is odd for me it works and doesn't cover the navigation

[link]http://gyazo.com/0dc318c09c255c6ef68f86626ea0f5b6

Comment: Yes, it's strange, I am also using other css files but they shouldn't affect the performance of the sidebar since they only style the links into buttons I'll upload them too, so you can see them

Comment: OK so on the #menuIzquierda do this margin-to: 40px; z-index: 999; on the .contenido float: right; You should see this. [link]http://gyazo.com/66c1f9764113e56411b489ea92155959 This is a start but I'm sure if you play around with some css then you can get it to work. This is what it looks like on the css [link]http://gyazo.com/b50e216e4119d80ff53bf536cba7598a

Comment: It works perfectly, I've tried it out with all the sites and it simply works!!! Thank you so much for your help. I'll upload a few screenshots so you'll see the result

Comment: You can check out the result here: http://imgbox.com/g/6DbpOeaDOl
Sorry I can't upvote since I haven't enough reputation

Comment: Looks great! and no worries I'm just glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use height: 100vh?

Or set it to top: 0 bottom: 0?

Comment: Height 100vh only works if the content on the right isn't bigger than 100% of the screen height, also setting top and bottom to 0 doesn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have two div **div_parent** and **div_child** the height of **div_child** should be 100%..so it can occupy the complete space of **div_parent**..

Comment: Unfortunately since it is made up of different php files, it is not possible to insert it into a parent div, it is actually using three divs, one on the top for the top menu, then the one on the left for the sidebar and finally another one for the content, each one with float left property

Comment: I build up a html site from different php files, and I wan't to style them with css

Comment: Quit simple why you are not apply external css file to your current html page..  like  **<link href="your-css-file.css" rel="stylesheet">**

Comment: I am using it, did you even look at the code?      
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style_app.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/buttons.css" />

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189610/how-to-make-a-page-with-header-and-left-sidebar                                                                                            see the link..

Comment: At this post they also state to use bottom 0, top 0 and left 0 which I already tried and didn't work :(