# How to Make a Webpage with Header, Left and Right Sidebars and a Footer?

Tags: html, css

I want it to have a header at the top which spans the width of the page, a main content part which has side bars either side and then a footer underneath. Unfortunately I am not very good when it comes to fixed, relative absolute and the measurements etc. so it is really appreciative.

I did use some of the code from here: [How to make a page with header and left-sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189610/how-to-make-a-page-with-header-and-left-sidebar)

But I edited it so the measurements were done in em not px as it makes it more scalable on devices.

Here is my current HTML layout

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');<!-- Custom Font -->
@charset "utf-8" @font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/*Layout for phones and tablets e.g. iPhone 5 and iPad*/


/*webpage fades in*/

html {
  animation: fadein 2s;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}


/*animation*/

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/*main colour settings for page*/

body {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 100px;
  padding: 25px;
}


/*Links*/

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 1s;
}


/*Link hovering*/

nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}


/*Main heading*/

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  left: 2em;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 2em;
}


/*Secondary heading*/

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}


/*Text*/

p {
  font-size: 0.75em;
}


/*Images*/

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  max-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

canvas {
  border: solid 1px black;
}


/*Footer*/

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}


/*Main Body*/

#mainContent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10em;
  top: 8em;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

#sideBar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 8em;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2em;
  border-right: solid 1px black;
  max-height: 2000px;
}

#sideBar img {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}


/*Light Switches*/

#lightSwitchOff {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#lightSwitchOn {
  display: inline;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/*Layout for desktop with a min-width of 1024px*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  p,
  li {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.75em;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 2.25em;
  }
  #enter {
    max-width: 60%;
    max-height: 60%;
  }
}


/*Layout for desktop with a min-width of 1280px (720p HD)*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
  li {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 2.25em;
  }
  #enter {
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
  }
}


/*Layout for desktop with a min-width of 1920px (1080p HD)*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
  p {
    font-size: 1.25em;
  }
  #enter {
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 40%;
  }
}


/*Layout for desktop with a min-width of 200px e.g. iMac*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 2000px) {
  p {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Sliding Game</h1>
</header>
<!--Closes Header -->

<div id="leftSideBar">
  <!-- Left Side Bar -->
  <h2>Select Image:</h2>
  <img src="images/dog.jpg" alt="Image Unvailable"></img>
  <img src="images/italy.jpg" alt="Image Unvailable"></img>
  <h2>Select Difficulty:</h2>
  <p id="easy">Easy</p>
  <p id="medium">Medium</p>
  <p id="hard">Hard</p>
  <button>Reset</button><br>
  <button>Randomise</button>
  <p>Timer:</p>
  <div id="timer">0</div><br>
</div>
<!-- Closes Left Side Bar -->

<div id="mainContent">
  <!-- Main Body -->
  <canvas id="game" width="600px" height="600px">Cavas is not available on your browser</canvas><br>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <div style="display: none">
    <img id="source" src="images/italy.jpg" alt="Image Unvailable">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Closes Main Content-->

<div id="rightSideBar">
  <!-- Right Side Bar -->
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
</div>
<!-- Closes Right Side Bar -->

<footer>
  Website Created by Ryan Simms <br> 16024828@stu.mmu.ac.uk <br>
</footer>
<!-- Closes Footer -->
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] with relevant CSS and actual scripts

Comment: Please post the CSS and markup here if you want help. On a size note, I wouldn't use em as a unit for layout; em simply means the declared number times the base amount. Use percentages for RWD unless you're using a preprocessor and declarative variables.

Comment: @mplungjan CSS has been posted

Comment: @TomReeves CSS has been posted

Comment: Please see the snippet I made. You can finish it by adding the relevant scripts and pictures from placeholder.com or lorempixel

Comment: @mplungjan the scripts and images don't matter right now as I have alt tags as placeholders for the images. These don't affect what the page layout will look like, just how some features will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for centering of elements on the webpage I would like you to recommend reading the following guide: [Centering in CSS: Complete guide,](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) and you can also use Flexbox for somewhat same result: [Complete guide to Flexbox.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

As for the header, I've made some code for you. You should checkout Bootstrap for easy positioning of elements on the webpage. They have specific classes for Navbars fixed bottom and top. Pretty easy framework!

```css
.header {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  position: relative;
  background: #353535;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  color: orange;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around; 
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 300px;
}
.div1 {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  width: 32%;
  background: #353535;
  margin-top: 20px;

}
.div2 {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 32%;
  background: #353535;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.div3 {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 32%;
  background: #353535;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h3 class="text">Your text here</h3>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
</div class="container">
```